# I need to print ints instead of list with values in python3

Tags: python, python-3.6

need some help. I just learning python for now and i have exercise in which i need to read inputs till input is less than 100 and print out all values in range 10 to 100
here is my code:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    number = int(input())
    if number < 10:
        continue
    elif number >= 100:
        break
    elif number in range(10, 100):
        numbers.append(number)
        print(numbers)
```

The problem is that I need to print individual numbers on separate lines and not the list of numbers.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i have to print just numbers at separate line and not the list of numbers

Comment: `for num in numbers: print(num)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since numbers lesser than 10 is ignored, you don't need to include it in part of your code.
If statement is executed consequentially, you have to have the numbers appended into the list before the loop is break.

```
numbers = []
while True:
    number = int(input())
    if number >= 10 and number <= 100:
        numbers.append(number)
    elif number>100:
        print (numbers)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*` operator here to unpack the list. Also, you can do this with just 2 `if` statements:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    number = int(input())
    if number < 10:
        continue
    if number > 100:
        break
    numbers.append(number)
        
print(*numbers, sep='\n')
```

Comment: this works in my terminal but something is wrong with hyperskil, thanks for help, i will try to find out what they want from me

Comment: @oleksandr_ievlakhov The problem is with this condition: `number >= 100`. It should be `number > 100`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
numbers = []
while True:
    number = int(input())
    if number < 10:
        continue
    elif number >= 100:
        break
    elif number in range(10, 100):
        numbers.append(number)
        
        print('____')
        for n in numbers:
            print(n)
        print('____')
```

Comment: still have a little problem.
Test input:
12
4
2
58
112
and my output is :
12
12
58
instead of :
12
58

Comment: It works for me, maybe you wrote "12" instead of "112", but you can fix with: if number not in numbers: numbers.append(number) etc.

Comment: i didn't write inputs, i'm doing exercise on hyperskill, but thanks i will try it.